# Using associative arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create something like a dictionary object where given a name as key, it should output its value.

Eg

```
dict["jerry"] should output 20 as value.
```

Or

```
var name = "jerry";
dict[name]  should output 20 as value
```

My code.

```
var totalAdditions = [];
totalAdditions.push({name:statsObj.author.login, value: additions});
//statsObj.author.login contains "jerry"

console.log(obj.login); //also contains value "jerry"
console.log(totalAdditions[obj.login]); //returns undefined??
```

Comment: `totalAdditions` is an array having keys as `0,1,2,....`, select specific object from array using `index` and then use `[](bracket notation)` to access the property...

Comment: The part following "My code" is completely unclear. What is `statsObj`? What is `obj`? How does that code, which is about an array of objects, have anything to do with the earlier code mapping `"jerry"` to 20?

Comment: You might consider using the new [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is there for these application cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays." It does have objects, which can do what you want, and `Map` (as of ES2015), which can also do what you want.

Object:

```js
var dict = Object.create(null); // Not {} so it doesn't inherit props like
                                // "toString", "valueOf", etc.
var name = "jerry";
dict["jerry"] = 20;
console.log(dict[name]); // 20
```

ES2015+ `Map`:

```js
let dict = new Map();
var name = "jerry";
dict.set("jerry", 20);
console.log(dict.get(name)); // 20
```